# adding infinite loop to carousel css3

Tags: css, carousel, infinite-loop

totally newbie question - trying to add an infinite loop to a forked carousel with this instruction to my css code :

```
 animation: carousel 10s infinite cubic-bezier(1, 0.015, 0.295, 1.225)` forwards;
```

...but not working at all.

css extract:

```
    .item {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: auto-flow;
  height: auto-flow;
  /* line-height: 200px; */
  /* font-size: 2em; */
  /* text-align: center; */
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.75;
  border-radius: 20px;

     animation: carousel 10s infinite cubic-bezier(1, 0.015, 0.295, 1.225) forwards;
```

}

I'd appreciate any help. Txs a lot.

forked code is [here.](https://codepen.io/fana1234/pen/ooMxVj)

Answer (score 1):

You should animate the `.carousel` element. Each slide movement, the .carousel element is get rotated by some degree. In order to animate this, you need to change the rotate value in keyframes.

```
@keyframes carousel{
    from {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}
```

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/dZjxGZ?editors=1100)**

Comment: txs Jinu. It's rotating, but now showing/rotating only the 1st slide... Probably some junk code left in mine...

Comment: I don't get it. I can see all slides are moving. Just inspect them and you will see.

Comment: yeap, you're right. Sorry, I was looking at another pen with (almost identical) same name. Thanks a lot :-)))